# How to remove a string from a list with a common part

Tags: python

I need to remove duplicate from a list with a common parts in python. My list is something like this:

```
- Addition  domainname1.com 80.80.80.80
+ Addition  domainname1.com 80.80.80.81
- Bitsquatting domainname2.com 104.160.171.87
+ Bitsquatting domainname2.com 104.160.172.85
- Homoglyph domainname3.com 206.188.193.4
- Insertion domainname4.com 206.188.200.6
- Insertion domainname5.com 206.188.200.7
+ Insertion domainname5.com 206.188.200.8
```

From this list I want to keep only the strings with unique domain name (and not string with common domain name and different IP) :

```
- Homoglyph domainname3.com 206.188.193.4
- Insertion domainname4.com 206.188.200.6
```

I tried to use `split()` to get a list of the domain name:

```
domainname1.com
domainname1.com
domainname2.com
domainname2.com
domainname3.com
domainname4.com
domainname5.com
domainname5.com
```

and remove the common domain name but I'm stuck to remove the corresponding string from the previous list.

```
for line in change:
    name = line.split()
    domain_name = name[2]
```

My way to get the domain name list (`change` is my initial list).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a new List, filling it with the changed values and then replace the original List ?

Comment: what is the *format* of the line? Is the `Addition`/`Bitsquating`/... always a *single* word?

Comment: yes the format line don't change its always `+ or -` `One word` `domainname` `IP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting unique hostnames

You can iterate over the lines, and each time add the domain name to a `set`, like:

```
my_set = {line.split()[2] for line in change}
the_domains = list(my_set)
```

Given all lines follow the format where the domain is one "word", and there are two "words" before that domain, this will do the trick.

The above does *not* guarantee that the order is maintained. If that is a requirement, you can use a uniqness filter, like:

```
def uniq(iterable):
    already = set()
    for x in iterable:
        if x not in already:
            yield x
            already.add(x)
```

Then we can process it like:

```
the_domains = list(uniq(line.split()[2] for line in change))
```

## Getting lines with unique hostnames

We can slightly generalize the `uniq` function to allow a key parameter, like:

```
def uniq(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    already = set()
    for x in iterable:
        fx = key(x)
        if fx not in already:
            yield x
            already.add(fx)
```

Then we can the *first* lines of the hostnames with:

```
the_domains = list(uniq(change, key=lambda line: line.split()[2]))
```

## Removing lines with a hostname that occurs twice or more

We can also remove all the lines with a hostname that occurs twice or more, by using a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def non_dup(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    iterable = list(iterable)
    cntr = Counter(map(key, iterable))
    return filter(lambda x: cntr[key(x)] < 2, iterable)
```

then we filter with:

```
the_domains = list(non_dup(change, key=lambda line: line.split()[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I already get the list of domain name and I need to keep the unique strings `- Insertion domainname4.com 206.188.200.6
- Insertion domainname5.com 206.188.200.7`  from the first list. In fact remove the strings with duplicate domain name

Comment: Almost it, `uniq` give a output without duplicate but i want to remove the duplicate (both strings) to keep only string without duplicate domain name in their strings as `Insertion domainname4.com 206.188.200.6 - Insertion domainname5.com 206.188.200.7`  in fact i would like to change my `change` first list into `Insertion domainname4.com 206.188.200.6 - Insertion domainname5.com 206.188.200.7`

Comment: @Pixels01: third edit :). I would however advise *not* to alter the list itself. It is not declarative and tends to introduce all sorts of bugs. Especially since you do not know which variables all hold a reference to the list. If you change the list, a lot of variables might change (sub)value as well.

Comment: Work perfectly. I was wondering how can we do it if the list changes format ? Because `line.split[2]` will don't work anymore ?

Comment: @Pixels01: you will need to update the `key=` with a function that manages to "capture" the hostname. For example with a regex. As long as the `key` is a function that takes as input a line, and as output a value that should be unique, you are fine.